# Imap library works perfect for gmail but why php imap library do not work for reading Webmail inbox

Tags: php, imap, webmail

hello guys hope you are doing well ! I am here with a problem related PHP Imap. I have done integration of Imap in Laravel. It reads my google mail like mymail@gmail.com successfully and works as aspected as i used gmail and created a secure app for password.
Have a look on code

```
  $user='myemail@gmail.com';
    $host='imap.gmail.com';
    $port=993
    $flag='/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert'
    $pass='uqqepunhujjwtutm';
    $server = new Server($host,$port,$flag);
$connection = $server->authenticate($user, $pass);
    return $connection;
```

It works perfect.
My problem is with reading webmail INBOX. when i change my credentials to read webmail

```
 $user='myemail@mydomain.com';
        $host='mail.domain.com';
        $port=993
        $flag='/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert'
        $pass='myWebmailPassword';
        $server = new Server($host,$port,$flag);
    $connection = $server->authenticate($user, $pass);
        return $connection;
```

it shows me error.

```
Host not found
```

did i Skip any webmail side or cpanel side configuration. ?

Please guide me any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Looks like the URL to the imap server might be wrong?

Comment: Try getting it working in an IMAP client like Thunderbird to prove that everything is working before using PHP/etc.  If Host is not found then “mail.domain.com” doesn’t exist.